# Loading pkcs8 throws malformed format in jsrsasign

Tags: javascript, digital-signature, digital-certificate, pkcs#8

I'm trying to sign a byte array using jsrsasign-5.0.7-all-min.js, but when I try to sign an error is thrown:

```
malformed format: SEQUENCE(0).items != 2: 1
```

History:

I have a pfx (wasn't created with openssl) file that I converted to pkcs5 using with the following openssl command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in signer001.pfx -nocerts -out signer001.key -nodes
```

jsrsasign threw an error; it couldn't find the encrypted header. So I  converted the file to pkcs8 with the following command

```
openssl pkcs8 -in signer001.key -topk8 -v2 des3 -out signer001pkcs8.key
```

I have the following code in javascript:

```
var password = "13245";
var pkcs8key = "" +
"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n" +
$('#keyb64').val() 
"-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";

console.log('OK');
var result = PKCS5PKEY.getKeyFromEncryptedPKCS8PEM(pkcs8key, password) ;
console.log("doesn't get executed");
```

I've tracked the error and is thrown inside the library itself. I checked the pkcs8 file in c# just to verify it is well constructed and it seems ok. Is there a bug in the library or am I missing something?

P.S. I took the example from [Digital signature with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678878/digital-signature-with-javascript) but it didn't work for me.

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

as I understand, pkcs8 is already decrypted, so, the

```
"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
```

should only be like:

```
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
```

I'm not very sure about it, but when I wrote the example [Digital signature with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678878/digital-signature-with-javascript) that was one of my mistakes :D

Comment: I removed the "ENCRYPTED" part from the header, but the library now throws a can't find PEM header: ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY

Comment: Please read spec this is not true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8